# NUnit test fails with System.OutOfMemoryException in TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity

I have a memory-intensive NUnit-based integration test, it needs about 3GB of heap space. It runs fine on my machine (from Resharper in x64 process), but it fails with System.OutOfMemoryException on the build server (TeamCity). The build agent has 24GB RAM and it is configured to run in the standard NUnit build step and is running on the x64 platform, version v4.0. How can I fix it?

The TeamCity is the latest version 8.1.5 (build 30240).

Comment: What's the test running?

Comment: teamcity is java based. could it be that you need to allow the JVM access to more memory?

Comment: The most obvious explanation, usually the correct one, is that the test runs in 32-bit mode.  You can't allocate 3 GB of virtual memory unless you run in 64-bit mode.  There are other reasons for OOM but not posting the stack trace of the exception doesn't help us help you.